# Devices and Printers hangs for a specific user

Tags: windows-7, printing

Windows 7 pro 64 on a domain.  Two users, both in the admin group.  One works fine, but for the other the Devices and Printers never loads completely.  It seems to hang with the status bar not quite complete, and nothing is shown.  I've read the various bluetooth related solutions but there's no bluetooth in use, and enabling the service didn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Edit: I am able to install printers, but it would still be really helpful to access this control.

Edit 2: More info.  I'm attempting to install network printers.  Printer Management shows the printers I've added as not installed, but that the drivers are installed.  When I add a printer with the Add Printer wizard it appears to work until the normal point when prompted about setting the printer as default when it errors with "Unable to set default printer".

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest reinstalling drivers. You can also try disabling the firewall to see if it loads.

Comment: Ugh, event log indicates it's probably related to corruption in the user specific registry files that are part of the roaming profile.

Comment: I read here that one of the causes could be user profile corruption. First answer tells you how to fix it. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/win-7-prof-64-bit-devices-and-printers-panel-wont/3083f8d4-7162-418f-bfab-cfd58c4479ae

Comment: @Rhyuk, yeah - that is probably what's happening.  Unfortunatley "repairing" a profile involves making a new one rather than actually repairing anything.  If this weren't a domain account that would be pretty simple, but it's going to involve more work for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by corrupt registry files in the roaming profile.

Answer (score 1):

See [Solve the loading problem - start 2 Bluetooth services](http://techietalkz.com/2009/10/02/how-to-solve-windows-7-devices-and-printers-forever-loading-and-blank/)
Don't forget to start both services; starting 1 of the 2 does not help, both are required! Weird, but it helped me and many others.